# Packet sniffer for link layer protocols

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, packet-sniffers

I am trying to convert a program called `Responder` which is written in Python to a C version. One of the spots I am stuck on is the listeners that listen on different ports. Responder listens for SMB on port 445 and 139. I created a small snippet that will listen on those ports as well. But when I run my program, I get no data.

```
void sniff(int PORT) {
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
       
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == 0) {
        return;
    }
       
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) {
        return;
    }

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
       
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0) {
        return;
    }

    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) {
        return;
    }
    printf("listen done.\n");
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) {
        return;
    }

    valread = read( server_fd , buffer, 1024);
    printf("%s\n",buffer );

    return;
}
```

If I do the above, I don't get anything.

Comment: What have you done to debug it so far?   I assume you have a debugger, and can set breakpoints, step, write print statements to show how the program is progressing and what the data is at various points, etc.

Comment: The code above will hang at the accept function. My understanding is nothing is connecting to it which makes sense. I am specifically trying to sniffer everything that I can see along my interface, like how Wireshark does.

Comment: If nothing is connecting, accept is supposed to block until a connection is present.  This is not the program hanging; this is the defined behaviour of accept.  So I am not sure what different behaviour you are expecting.

Comment: @vs123 This code is creating a TCP server that waits for clients to connect to it. If you are trying to write a packet sniffer instead, you need to use an `AF_PACKET` socket instead, put into promiscuous mode via `setsockopt()` if needed, and using `recvfrom()` or `recvmsg()` to read packets passing through the network.  See [Capture Ethernet frames using an AF_PACKET socket in C](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/capture_ethernet_frames_using_an_af_packet_socket_in_c.html) for more details.